# Remove duplicate rows on many to many table (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table which is many to many and my table looks like this

```
+----+--------+
|  Customers  |
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | john   |
| 1  | john   |
| 1  | james  |
| 2  | george |
| 2  | michael|
+----+--------+
```

What i want is to remove the duplicate rows with the same name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621314/how-to-remove-mysql-duplicate-entries

Comment: Do you want to delete them from the table or just query and see them once?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just want to delete them and clean my table.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This may be a(/the) problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have no way to distinguish one row from another.  So, the easiest way to do this is the temporary table approach:

```
create table temp as
    select distinct id, name
    from customers;

truncate table customers;

insert into customers(id, name)
    select id, name
    from temp;

drop table temp;
```

Comment: you mention the "easiest way" is there another way? just curious.

Comment: @Incognito . . . What comes to mind is altering the table, adding a column, setting that column to a unique value in each row, and then deleting all but the minimum or maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GROUP BY aggregate function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Well a small variation @Gordon Linoff answer, is by avoiding the "Insert into" and doing a "Rename table" and making the queries to work on any table.

**Solution-1:** By using a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE table_name_clean AS SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    table_name;

DROP TABLE table_name;

RENAME TABLE table_name_clean TO table_name;
```

**Solution-2:** Adding a UNIQUE INDEX (recommended as it will prevent the creation of  duplicate entries in your table)

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX u_id (id,name);
```